# Similar reference for different tabs in tab widget ? Strange

Tags: python, qt, tabs, pyqt, tabwidget

I am creating tabs dynamically in a tabwidget using this method :

```
 def add_new_tab(self,index,text):

    self.new_tab = InterfaceTemplateDialog()
    self.tabs.addTab(self.new_tab,text)
    self.tabs.setTabText(index,text)
```

Trying to print the reference of selected tab using this method :

```
def onChange(self):

    currentIndex = self.tabs.currentIndex()
    print InterfaceTemplateDialog()
```

I get the same reference for every selected tab except for the first selected:

```
<OptionsTRANUS.interface_template.InterfaceTemplateDialog object at 0x0000000014F842F0>
<OptionsTRANUS.interface_template.InterfaceTemplateDialog object at 0x0000000014F8EE18>
<OptionsTRANUS.interface_template.InterfaceTemplateDialog object at 0x0000000014F8EE18>
<OptionsTRANUS.interface_template.InterfaceTemplateDialog object at 0x0000000014F8EE18>
<OptionsTRANUS.interface_template.InterfaceTemplateDialog object at 0x0000000014F8EE18>
```

If references are similar, I cannot control actions on tabs.

So what is this strange problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way to get the correct reference is to use :

currentTabWidget = self.tabs.currentWidget()

with self.tabs = self.findChild(QtGui.QTabWidget, 'tabWidget')

I tested, it works well. Thanks.